# Windows Phone mediaelement error 3123

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I'm creating a media element inside a wp7 application programmatically and then I'm adding it to a visible grid as a child. The problem is that I receive this error message (inside the MediaFailed event handler) "3123 An error has occurred.".

This is the url used: http://www.educationalquestions.com/video/ELL_PART_5_768k.wmv.

Any ideas about the source of the problem (I have the `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB` capability set as well as the `ID_CAP_NETWORKING`)?

Comment: does the content play on the device at all? (i.e. via the MediaPlayer launcher or in a MediaElement created at design time in XAML?)

Comment: it doesn't work on the device and I can't edit the xaml of the page because everything is programmatically generated (I'm implementing a widget for a mobile sdk - MoSync sdk); I was just asking to see if someone knows what could be the source of the error (because the error message doesn't tell me anything) - the link works just fine in a native application using a media element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of module were initialized behind the scenes when a windows phone application was created using mosync: one of them is the CameraModule that uses a VideoBrush and its source was set using a PhotoCamera. Because the VideoBrush is based on a MediaElement and inside a wp7 application only one MediaElement can be used, the second one (mine) was not working. A workaround in the initialization of the CameraModule solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my WP8, Windows Phone 8, project - it was caused by me removing the `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK` capability from the WMAppManifest.xml file...

Just though I would append it to this case, since this was the first question I found with this error code...